# Counting the number of abelian groups of a certain order

Tags: group-theory

Good day all,

Wikipedia states:
There are 2328 groups of order 128 up to ismorphism. How is this calculated? Also, what does "up to isomorphism" mean?

(I know what an isomorphism is...i'm just unsure of the phrasing "up to...")
Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you just mean "2328 groups of order 128".  There aren't so many abelian groups (of order 128).

Comment: You are correct, I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Actually, you took "abelian" out of the question but not out of the title of your question. And you accepted my answer over Eric's, even though mine only addresses the question with abelian groups and his talks about finite groups in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groups $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)^\times$ and $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ are different, but they are isomorphic. If you literally counted all the groups of a given order, that would be like counting sets of a given order - given any cardinal numbers $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ one can exhibit $\kappa$-many sets of size $\lambda$ that are all different, so this is a pointless question to ask because there is no limit to how many sets of some size there can be. Instead, when we count groups we count isomorphic groups as the same.

Anyway, we use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups. If $n$ is a whole number with prime factorization $\prod p^e$, and $f(n)$ denotes the number of abelian groups of size $n$, then we can say that $f(n)=\prod f(p^e)$, and moreover that $f(p^e)$ equals the number of integer partitions of the integer $e$. In this case, $128=2^7$ and there are $15$ integer partitions of $7$, so there are $15$ abelian groups of order $2^7$.

Note that $2328$ counts the number of finite groups of order $2^7$, not the number of finite abelian groups of that order. Counting those is very nontrivial.

Comment: How do these multiply? meaning: say I had two groups of orders: 2^7=|g| and 3^4=|h| If I wanted the number of finite groups of the form gh, would I find integer partitions of 7 and 4 and then multiply them?

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent : Your method works for abelian groups.  (Although you way of saying it is a little odd.  I'd say there are that many abelian groups of order $2^7 \cdot 3^4$.)  Not for general groups, though; there can be more than one way to make a "product group" from one set of choices of partitions.

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent The way you've phrased your question (in your comment) is nonsense. The number of finite abelian groups of order $2^73^4$ equals $15$ (the number of integer partitions of $7$) times $5$ (the number of integer partitions of $4$), i.e. $15\times5=75$ abelian groups of order $2^73^4$. Counting the number of *not necessarily abelian* groups of order $2^73^4$ would be a much harder task (and there would be much more of them). You will need a stronger background in group theory before you understand how the number of not-necessarily-abelian groups of a given size is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Up to isomorphism:  Groups are sets with an operation.  The sets of the groups $\langle a \mid a^2 \rangle$ and $\langle b \mid b^2 \rangle$ are different, so the groups are different.  However, the isomorphism $a \leftrightarrow b$ shows that they're isomorphic, hence "the same".  That is, one may be made into the other solely through relabelling.

Counting groups can be hard, especially groups of power-of-2 order.  See [*The groups of order 128*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939090244I) by Rodney James, M. F. Newman and E. A. O'Brien, Journal of Algebra, ISSN 00218693, Volume 129,Number 1, Page 136 - 158(February 1990).  They used a computer search.  The paper seems to be accessible online, so you can read the many, many methods and previous results that went into this computation.